# .NET Service container without serialization

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am looking for a framework/container for .NET that will allow me to create, use services (in the true sense of that word - not "web" services) at runtime, with all invocations and data transfer being in .NET - without serialization into SOAP or over HTTP (i.e. like WCF does).

Is there anything like this out there?
Thanks

Comment: @PeterRitchie but doesn't that still involve serializing into binary and deserializing from it?

Comment: Not sure I follow, of course binary involves serializing into and from binary.  But your question detailed SOAP or over HTTP, neither of which is mandatory with WCF you could use binary over TCP, binary over named pipes, etc...  Not that SOAP or XML isn't ".NET"...

Comment: When you call a method `string getFoo()` in just a simple program, what happens? Does string get serialized? No - you just get a pointer to the memory location. That is what I am asking - can one have services where the objects are passed around only by references.

Comment: You can't pass pointers to memory from one process to another--they have they own address space.

Comment: @PeterRitchie You're right, but what about if services resided within the same process?

Comment: if they're in the same process and you don't want to serialize, call methods.

Comment: @PeterRitchie I agree. But wouldn't it be nice to have the same notion of "services", even within the same process? Then we can write interfaces and share those as contracts. Other services can "acquire" any other services. We can have a service runtime that will allow dynamic loading of new services (based on some metadata associated with a "service" package). It would seem like a nice abstraction and I was just wandering if .NET has something along these lines.

Comment: Why?  That's what assemblies, classes, and methods are for.  IOC containers could be used to get decoupled "services", if needed.

Comment: @PeterRitchie Services are dynamic. Method calls and classes are static. Services may come and go, while it is rather hard to "add" a class or a method at runtime, without resorting to reflection. One example of a service container is an OSGi component system (I don't know why they went through all the trouble of writing it if one could simply use methods - surely there must be some advantage).

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to transfer data beyond your currently executing AppDomain, there is going to be serialization of some kind, but you can control what that is.

WCF allows for binary, SOAP and custom serializers.  As far as the communication method is concerned, you still have a good many options, WCF will natively support Named Pipes, TCP, HTTP and again, custom options.  If you are operating within a single machine, Named Pipes would probably fit your bill as it uses shared memory which can produce high throughput, low latency IPC.

If, however, you are not needing to separate AppDomains, consider using an IOC container such as Unity (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203104.aspx) or any of the other options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515124/whats-the-simplest-ioc-container-for-c.  An IOC Container will let you instantiate your "Service" and call it without knowing how to instantiate the object.  It can provide some of the same decoupling benefits that WCF and other web services make neccessary.

tl;dr: there will always be serialization if two processes are used.  Try IOC to avoid that performance hit.

Comment: The thing is, we have constraint that requires us to use WCF for communication with external clients. I thought it would make sense to write some of our components as services as well - and if WCF did it's communication in .NET when inside the "domain" we'd be set.

Comment: You can use WCF for both if you want to.  You have a lot of reading and background to do on WCF, what it is, and how it works IMO.

Comment: Thanks, I actually think IOC might be sufficient for me. But what if I don't want to transfer data beyond AppDomain, but still want all the advantages of services, like ability to acquire services at runtime dynamically?

Comment: If you wrap WCF service clients in a small proxy that handles lifetimes, service location and bindings, you can have the WCF services exposed via IOC.  Then, the client to the service has no idea whether it is coming from WCF or whether it is just a local implementation of the interface.  You do, however, have non-trivial problems to overcome with this route, not limited to WCF Channel Lifetimes, multithreaded clients, impersonation, and the largest of all - exception handling.  Since the client doesn't know it is WCF, you need to map FaultExceptions to other types.

Answer (score 1):

WCF doesn't restrict you to using SOAP over HTTP -- this is a common misconception.  You can use WCF with a number of different underlying [endpoints](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation#endpoints).

WCF is the way almost everyone goes for this type of thing -- either that or .NET Remoting, but you don't see a lot of .NET Remoting around anymore.

Comment: So... can on communicate between services without any type of serialization?

Comment: No.  If you want to send objects over the wire, you are by definition using serialization, no matter what framework you use, as Mitch eluded to in his answer.  There will be objects you'll never be able to truly serialize though.  For example, a Graphics device context in Windows Forms.  That's specific to an application and can't be serialized, no matter what framework you use.  You could roll your own framework and just shove bytes around, but that is, I promise, not going to be fun.

Comment: What I mean is, if there is a framework that essentially manages classes and objects - kind of like Dependency Injection frameworks, but also manages the acquisition of services at runtime, startup, shutdown. So like a small OS. In that case, one would simply "shove" objects around - since everything is going on inside .NET. I am really doing a poor job at explaining this aren't I?

Comment: As soon as you start talking about moving objects "over the wire" (or shoving them around) you have to serialize/de-serialize. Object storage in the CLR is undefined, and in memory. As soon as you want to transfer what it models out of memory, you have to define how that is done.  You get included serializers to do that for you, if you want, but that work has be done at some point.

Comment: @drozzy: What you're describing is WCF.